# android sqlite query "!=" multiple whereargs

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to retrieve a rows from my database that have a specific value in their date column and a non-zero value in their total column.

The following code, which only retrieves rows based on date, works.

```
private String[] whereArgs = new String[]{
        "12/28/2011"
};

protected Cursor doQuery() {
        Cursor result =
                db
                        .getReadableDatabase()
                        .query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE,
                                new String[]{"ROWID AS _id",
                                        DatabaseHelper.TAG,
                                        DatabaseHelper.DATE,
                                        DatabaseHelper.EXPRESSION,
                                        DatabaseHelper.TOTAL},
                                DatabaseHelper.DATE + "=?",
                                whereArgs,
                                null, null, DatabaseHelper.DATE);

        result.getCount();

        return (result);
    }
```

This code attempts to return rows with a specific date and exclude rows with a value of zero using a "!=" operator.

It returns an empty cursor.

```
    private String[] whereArgs = new String[]{
        "12/28/2011",
        "0"
};

protected Cursor doQuery() {
        Cursor result =
                db
                        .getReadableDatabase()
                        .query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE,
                                new String[]{"ROWID AS _id",
                                        DatabaseHelper.TAG,
                                        DatabaseHelper.DATE,
                                        DatabaseHelper.EXPRESSION,
                                        DatabaseHelper.TOTAL},
                                DatabaseHelper.DATE + "=?"
                                        + " AND " +
                                DatabaseHelper.TOTAL + " != ?",
                                whereArgs,
                                null, null, DatabaseHelper.DATE);

        result.getCount();

        Log.v("CURSOR", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(result));

        return (result);
    }
```

And here is the logcat output of the dumpCursorToString method that proves it returns empty

```
01-26 15:35:40.920 22138-22153/com.example.ryan.caloriecalc1 V/CURSOR: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@4c46fc9
                                                                   <<<<<
```

Comment: What happens if you forgo the whereargs and just do `...TOTAL + "!=0",`?

Comment: That worked. I just had to change it to "!=0.0" because of the way it was being stored in the database. I'm guessing the reason why the cursor was being returned empty is the type of the whereargs wasn't compatible with what was being retrieved from the database. Thanks!

Comment: @323go meant to tag you in the previous comment thanking you.

Comment: Good deal, glad you got it worked out.